# Android Gradle: How can I use the "debug" sources as a "provided" dependency for "release" builds

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

TL;DR: Is it possible to add the "debug" Java sources of an Android Gradle build as a "provided" dependency for the "release" build?

I am using the standard Android Gradle build file for my application.  When I run `./gradlew build` it produces both a "release" and "debug" APK.  This is expected.

I have some extra classes in `src/main/debug` that add some extra functionality to debug builds, functionality that should never ship in the release builds.  For example, there is a `BroadcastReceiver` that responds to commands issued via `adb shell am broadcast ...` and another class to set a `StrictMode` policy.  Neither of these classes should even *exist* in the "release" APK, let alone be used by code in the "release" APK.

These "debug" classes are initialized in `Application.onCreate()`.  However, since these classes do not even exist in "release" builds I have chosen to add "stub" versions of these classes into `src/release/java` so that the release builds compile.

What I would *like* to do is delete the stubs from `src/release/java` and protect all calls to the classes that exist only in `src/debug/java` by something like the following:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    DebugBroadcastReceiver.register(this);
    StrictModePolicy.enable(this);
}
```

The challenge is that since these classes do not even exist in the "release" Java source directories the Java compilation fails because the referenced classes that only exist in the "debug" directory are not on the classpath.

What I would like to do to fix this is to somehow modify `build.gradle` to include the compiled `.class` files from `src/debug/java` as a "provided" dependency for the "release" build.  My understanding of a "provided" dependency is that the dependency will be on the classpath during compilation but will *not* be included in the resulting APK, which is exactly what I want.

So far, I've tried the following in `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    // a bunch of dependencies that are omitted for brevity
    releaseProvided project(path: ":app", configuration: "debug")
}
```

but it fails with the following:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Cannot evaluate module app : Configuration with name 'debug' not found.
```

Can someone with Gradle & Android expertise suggest a way to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1):

Create a subclass of your application in `src/debug/java`. Use the same package but a different class name. Override `onCreate()` and invoke the debug classes here.

Add a manifest to `src/debug`, and override the application class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          package="com.yourapp">

    <application
        android:name=".YourAppDebug"
        tools:replace="android:name">
    </application>
</manifest>
```